# Retrieving the number of breaks in a FLowLayout

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I want to programatically retrieve the number of breaks/newlines in a `TFlowLayout`.

I have a simple `TFlowLayout` with 4 regular controls inside (The `TFlowLayout` does not contain any `TFlowLayoutBreak` controls).

Depending on the width of the layout it looks like:

```
// * = control

// Scenario #1: No breaks
* * * *

// Scenario #2: 1 break
* * * 
*

// Scenario #3: 2 breaks
* * 
* * 

// Scenario #4: 3 breaks
*
*
*
*
```

Is it possible to retrieve the number of breaks of a `TFlowLayout` programatically or can I only go off the width of the layout to determine the number of breaks?

Comment: Looks like the # of unique Y values set for the controls in the `.Controls` array would give you this.

Comment: That is so simple, yet brilliant, Brian. I was looking at how TFlowLayout.DoRealign is implemented and was going to suggest Bas might need to replicate part of it

Comment: @Brian Thank you! Very nice and elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counting the changes in Y values for the controls looks to work since the array is in layout order.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Cnt, I : integer;
begin
  if FlowLayout1.ControlsCount = 0 then Cnt := 0 else Cnt := 1;
  for I := 1 to FlowLayout1.ControlsCount - 1 do
    if FlowLayout1.Controls[I-1].Position.Y <> FlowLayout1.Controls[I].Position.Y then inc(cnt);
  button1.Text := IntToStr(Cnt);
end;
```